# Unable to select database using mysqli_select_db

Tags: php

```
<?php // sqltest.php
$db_hostname='localhost';
$db_database='book';
$db_username='';
$db_password='';

$db_server = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($db_server,$db_database )
or die("Unable to select database: " . mysqli_error($db_server));
```

I am using localhost:8080 and localhost:8080/phpMyAdmin to access the whole thing. Now I have code which runs like you see above and getting error message unable to select database. What should I do to remove the error.

Comment: You have to set username and password

Comment: @EugeneSmith Do you expect the OP to put the username and password on a public place like Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 2):

You don't do `mysql_select_db`. You do this way:

```
$db_server = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
```

See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php):

> **Note:** This function should only be used to change the default database for the connection. You can select the default database with 4th parameter in `mysqli_connect()`.